# Error with file size of assembly bootloader

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader

I'm having trouble assembling x86 assembly code into a bootable image file. Below is the code I'm working with:

```
org 0x7C00
bits 16

%define ENDL 0x0D, 0x0A

start:
    jmp main

;
; Prints a string to the screen
; Params:
;   - ds:si points to string
;
puts:
    ; save registers we will modify
    push si
    push ax
    push bx

.loop:
    lodsb               ; loads next character in al
    or al, al           ; verify if next character is null?
    jz .done

    mov ah, 0x0E        ; call BIOS interrupt
    mov bh, 0           ; set page number to 0
    int 0x10

    jmp .loop

.done:
    pop bx
    pop ax
    pop si    
    ret

main:
    ; setup data segments
    mov ax, 0           ; can't set ds/es directly
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax

    ; setup stack
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 0x7C00      ; stack grows downwards from where we are loaded in memory

    ; print welcome message
    mov si, welcome_msg
    call puts

    ; jump to desktop
    call desktop

.halt:
    jmp .halt

desktop:
    ; clear screen
    mov ah, 0x00       ; function 0 of int 10h: set video mode
    mov al, 0x03       ; video mode 3 (text mode 80x25)
    int 0x10

    ; print UI
    mov si, desktop_ui
    call puts

    ; get user input
    mov si, user_input
    call puts
    mov ah, 0x0       ; function 0 of int 16h: read keyboard input
    int 0x16
    cmp al, 'l'       ; check if input is 'logout'
    je .logout

    ; handle user input
    mov si, user_input
    cmp si, logout_string  ; compare user input with "logout"
    je .logout
    cmp si, files_string   ; compare user input with "files"
    je .files
    cmp si, office_string  ; compare user input with "office"
    je .office
    cmp si, about_string   ; compare user input with "about"
    je .about

    ; invalid input, loop again
    jmp desktop

.logout:
    ; logout procedure
    ; (could perform cleanup tasks here if necessary)
    jmp main

.files:
    ; handle files option
    ; (could implement file management functionality here)
    jmp desktop

.office:
    ; handle office option
    ; (could implement office suite functionality here)
    jmp desktop

.about:
    ; display about information
    mov si, about_msg
    call puts
    jmp desktop

welcome_msg: db '  officerdownOS', ENDL, '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------', ENDL, '                                  TYPE LOGOUT TO LOGOUT', ENDL, '   ---------------                  ---------------                  ----------------', ENDL, '    PRODUCTIVITY!                           ?                             files', ENDL, '  -----------------                 ----------------                 -----------------', ENDL, '     Office Suite                        About                            files', 0
desktop_ui: db 'Enter your choice: ', 0
user_input: times 256 db 0
logout_string: db 'logout', 0
files_string: db 'files', 0
office_string: db 'office', 0
about_string: db 'about', 0
about_msg: db 'officerdownOS Normal v1.1', ENDL, 'Compiled 11/18/2023', ENDL, 0

; Fill remaining space in the boot sector with zeros
times (512-($-$$)) db 0

dw 0xAA55
```

When I run

```
nasm -f bin bootloader.asm -o bootloader.bin
```

I get the error

```
bootloader.asm:120: error: TIMES value -459
```

I've tried modifying the numbers, but I haven't been successful. I'm not exactly sure what to do, and I would appreciate any help or guidance on resolving this issue. Thank you!

I have further leaned that the file is too big. I want to keep the specified UI in this bootloader but I am not sure how. Here is the updated code:

```
org 0x7C00
bits 16

start:
    jmp main

;
; Prints a string to the screen
; Params:
;   - ds:si points to string
;
puts:
    pusha               ; save registers we will modify

.loop:
    lodsb               ; loads next character in al
    or al, al           ; verify if next character is null?
    jz .done

    mov ah, 0x0E        ; call BIOS interrupt
    mov bh, 0           ; set page number to 0
    int 0x10

    jmp .loop

.done:
    popa                ; restore registers
    ret

main:
    ; setup data segments
    xor ax, ax
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax

    ; setup stack
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 0x7C00      ; stack grows downwards from where we are loaded in memory

    ; print welcome message
    mov si, welcome_msg
    call puts

    ; jump to desktop
    call desktop

.halt:
    jmp .halt

desktop:
    ; clear screen
    mov ah, 0x00       ; function 0 of int 10h: set video mode
    mov al, 0x03       ; video mode 3 (text mode 80x25)
    int 0x10

    ; print UI
    mov si, desktop_ui
    call puts

    ; get user input
    mov si, user_input
    call puts
    mov ah, 0x0       ; function 0 of int 16h: read keyboard input
    int 0x16
    cmp al, 'l'       ; check if input is 'logout'
    je .logout

    ; handle user input
    mov si, user_input
    cmp si, logout_string  ; compare user input with "logout"
    je .logout
    cmp si, files_string   ; compare user input with "files"
    je .files
    cmp si, office_string  ; compare user input with "office"
    je .office
    cmp si, about_string   ; compare user input with "about"
    je .about

    ; invalid input, loop again
    jmp desktop

.logout:
    ; logout procedure
    ; (could perform cleanup tasks here if necessary)
    jmp main

.files:
    ; handle files option
    ; (could implement file management functionality here)
    jmp desktop

.office:
    ; handle office option
    ; (could implement office suite functionality here)
    jmp desktop

.about:
    ; display about information
    mov si, about_msg
    call puts
    jmp desktop

welcome_msg: db 'o','f','f', 4 DUP('i'),'c','e','r','d','o','w','n','O','S', 13, 10
            db '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------', 13, 10
            db '                                  TYPE LOGOUT TO LOGOUT', 13, 10
            db '   ---------------                  ---------------                  ----------------', 13, 10
            db '    PRODUCTIVITY!                           ?                             files', 13, 10
            db '  -----------------                 ----------------                 -----------------', 13, 10
            db '     Office Suite                        About                            files', 0

desktop_ui: db 'Enter your choice: ', 0
user_input: times 256 db 0
logout_string: db 'logout', 0
files_string: db 'files', 0
office_string: db 'office', 0
about_string: db 'about', 0
about_msg: db 'officerdownOS Normal v1.1', 13, 10
            db 'Compiled 11/18/2023', 13, 10, 0

; Fill remaining space in the boot sector with zeros
times 510-($-$$) db 0

dw 0xAA55
```

and the error i get is:

```
bootloader.asm:121: error: TIMES value -457 is negative
```

Comment: Boot sectors can be at most 512 bytes, or 510 not counting the 2-byte signature at the end.  Your `welcome_msg` is huge, pushing the size well above that.  (`nasm -l /dev/stdout  foo.asm` will make a listing to the terminal where you can see addresses.  0x1fe is the last byte you can use and still have room for the MBR signature.)

Comment: I would like to have that specific UI. Is there another way I could trim it without messing with the UI?

Comment: You might be able to write code that outputs that string in fewer total bytes of code + data.  It has some long repeats, so perhaps a run-length encoding scheme could work, perhaps with byte values from 0 to 0x19 other than 0xD / 0xA  (CR LF newline) meaning to repeat the next character that many times, or that many times plus 1 ot 2.  And there's probably room to save bytes in the other part of your code; see [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/132981) for various tricks to help cram this into 510 bytes.

Comment: Or of course you could just load more sectors from disk.

Comment: Look at my edited version.

Comment: Where?  I only see an edit from 24 minutes ago to fix a title typo.

Comment: Sorry. I just edited it.

Comment: As I am just trying to make an OS, should I just move this UI to C and use the ASM bootloader?

Comment: Well yeah, cramming more code and UI into a 510-byte MBR gets increasingly difficult as you want to add more functionality.  If you plan for this to be larger later, you should definitely just go with bootloader + "kernel".  The "kernel" can be written in asm if you want, or C or C++ are good choices especially if you switch to protected mode, but then you need drivers for keyboard input and manual VGA output.  If you want C or C++, might be easier to build a UEFI application which is probably easier to boot on modern PCs.

Comment: Re: your update: your code + data is now 2 bytes smaller.  The calculated size of filler needed to put the `dw 0xaa55` at the end of 512 bytes went from `-459` to `-457`, so you're still too large by 457 bytes.  (The `510 - ($-$$)` calculation is `510 - size of previous stuff`, and the result has to be non-negative for it to assemble.)